# dc.js: stacked area chart using reduceCount method

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm fairly new to the dc.js/crossfilter/d3 trifecta, and have a question about grouping variables for building a stacked area chart. I've been following tutorials like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/697043/Making-Dashboards-with-Dc-js-Part-2-Graphing) that show how to generate a time series chart. This has been really useful, however my method of defining the `.group()` method of the chart is slightly different. In the example, the author has data of the form `{'date': somedate, 'http_404': 20, 'total': 340 ... }` where each type of http request has some sort of explicit value associated with the http key. It's then straightforward to employ the `.reduceSum()` method to group the number of overall http requests by date like so `var hits = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.total})`.

The author then defines a variable for each type of http request in order to define a series for each like so `var http_404 = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.http_404})`. These variables are then fed to the `.group()` and `.stack()` methods in the chart sections in the code. This makes sense to me. However, I'm using data where there is no pre-calculated value for variables I would like to plot, and instead I need to simply count the number of records in my data that contain a certain value. So I have something of the form:

`'name', 'occupation', 'group', 'date_joined'
'John', 'plumber', 'A', '12/01/01'
'Jane', 'programmer', 'B', '12/22/04'
'Jim', 'manager', 'B', '1/8/05'
'Jill', 'motivational speaker', 'A', '5/14/12'`

where I need to be able to count how many people are in a certain group and plot each as a series over time and use these as a `.stack()` in the time chart I'm creating. I know I need to use the `.reduceCount()` method, and this has worked for simply counting the total number of records split by day, but I'm unsure about how to split out the different groups. I suspect my misunderstanding stems from lack of overall knowledge about map-reduce heuristics, so any pointers on the basics of that, especially as they pertain to crossfilter, would be greatly appreciated. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

**UPDATE:** I've been able to plot multiple series, but I the resulting graph is incorrect. I've tried implementing a conditional that checks which group the records are in and assigns them to variables like so: `var group_A = dateDim.group().reduceCount(function(d) {if (d.group == "A") {return d.group} })` and the same for the B group. However, when I plot these, I get two series that have the same values duplicated at each data point stacked on top of one another. Any insight on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.  To get it working the way you tried, you'll want your reduce function to (always) return a value, so

```
var group_A = dateDim.group().reduceCount(function(d) {
    if (d.group == "A") return 1; 
    else return 0; 
});
```

Another thing people commonly do is reduce all the values into one composite group:

```
var group = dateDim.group().reduce(function(p, d) {
    p[d.group] = (p[d.group] || 0) + 1;
    return p;  
  },
  function(p, d) {
    --p[d.group];
    return p;
  },
  function() { return {}; }
);
```

Then you'd use accessors for your [stack calls](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#stackgroup-name-accessor):

```
.stack(group, function(d) { return d["A"] || 0; })
```

Comment: I think I'm confused by the stack call. Should the `group` variable be the `group_A` variable that was defined with the custom reduce function? Otherwise, I don't understand where this new `group` variable is coming from. Haven't quite got it working yet, but thanks for looking.

Comment: Another thing I'm noticing: when I print individual objects from the `group_A` variable as defined by the custom reduce function, I get objects that have dates as their keys (which is what I want), but then values that are dictionary-like objects. Within these value objects, each group shows up with a value of `NaN` like so: `Object: {key: 'some_date', value: {'group_A': 'NaN', 'group_B': 'NaN'}`. I have no idea why it's not counting for each group... This, does prompt a further question: will the method I have described work if each group doesn't have a value or count at all the same dates?

Comment: Okay, I've corrected the code to deal with values being initially undefined.  Obviously this was untested.  The first method is more resilient but less efficient since it has to read all the values for each date for each group.

Comment: Okay, this helps for the actual passing of the variables to the `.stack()` method. Thanks so much for looking at this again. However, I'm still having a problem where all the values in the `var group` variable are `NaN`s. So, this must mean the issue lies in how I'm implementing the `reduce` function right?

Comment: Yeah, set breakpoints in the reduce functions and see what's going wrong.  You saw my correction to the reduce-add function right?  The debugger knows.

Comment: Ok, finally have it reading in data. You can view the resulting chart [here](http://unc.edu/~shafferk/catl_interface/help.html), raw data [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kylejshaffer/905bad685b888e9edbb8/raw/bd02c9be15f9e77e888d4e15f4e55116e44b8402/rides.csv). If you Inspect Element in Chrome, you'll see the second element of the variable I'm sending to the `.group` method in lineChart printed. It has values now, but the chart is plotting undefined values for each date (you'll see a tool-tip if you hover near the top border of the chart). Thanks again for working with me on this.

Comment: Finally got [something working](http://unc.edu/~shafferk/catl_interface/help.html). Code available [here](view-source:http://www.unc.edu/~shafferk/catl_interface/help.html). Thanks for your help.