# d3.js Stacked Area chart - not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am constructing a stacked area graph (following [this tutorial](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/stackedarea_wideinput.html)) and am having issues with the graph rendering. The axes render correctly, but the area elements do not appear. When using just one column of the data it works fine, but after stacking the data, no luck.

I feel that the issue is with my use of `scaleLinear()`.

I've tried two methods: putting `y` values from the `d3.stack` function I get negative values out (commented in code below). Secondly, to debug, I set the maximum to the maximum of `stackedData` (set to default in code below). This gives all positive values out when I use `console.log`, but no graph renders.

Here's the code:

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 70},
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width",width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height",height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");
let data = []
var group_names = []
//Assumes first line of data is table header, otherwise will not work properly
model.output_energy_demand.map(function(x,i){
  if(i==0) {
    group_names = x
  }else{
    let line = {}
    x.map(function(y,j){
      line[group_names[j]]=y
    });
    data.push(line)
  }
});

data.forEach((d,i)=>{
    var keys = Object.keys(d)
    console.log(model.year[i])
    d["year"] = d3.timeParse("%Y")(model.year[i])
    for(var j=0;j<keys.length;j++){
      d[keys[i]] = +d[keys[j]]
    }
  });
if(typeof(data)!="undefined") {
  console.log("Data loaded")
  console.log(model.year)

  //Stacking data
  var sumstat = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.year;})
    .entries(data);

  var stackedData = d3.stack()
  .keys(group_names)
  .value(function(d,key){
    return d.values[0][key]
  })(sumstat);

  //Set up axes
  var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(model.year.map((d,i)=>{return d3.timeParse("%Y")(d)})))
    .range([0,width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("x",width*.5)
    .attr("y",height+margin.bottom)
    .style("text-anchor","middle")
    .attr("font-family","Tahoma")
    .text("Year")

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  // Finds maximum of stackedData, which avoids negative values (but gives incorrect values on the y-axis) 
  .domain([0,d3.max(stackedData,
    function(d){
      //Find maximum value of data
      var max = 0;
      d.forEach(function(e,i){
        console.log(e);
        if(d3.max(e)>max) max=d3.max(e)
    })
    return max
    })
  ])
 // Finds maximum of stackedData, which gives correct values on the y-axis, but causes negative values to come out of y(d[0])
// .domain([0,d3.max(data,
  //   function(d){
  //     //Find maximum value of data
  //     var max = 0;
  //     group_names.forEach(function(key,i){
  //       console.log(key);
  //       if(d[key]>max) max=d[key]
  //   })
  //   return max
  //   })
  // ])
  .range([ height,0])

  svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("y",-margin.left)
    .attr("x",-height*.5)
    .attr("dy","1em")
    .style("text-anchor","middle")
    .attr("font-family","Tahoma")
    .attr("transform","rotate(-90)")
    .text("Energy Demand (TWh /year)")

  console.log("About to plot data ")
  svg
    .selectAll("layers")
    .data(stackedData)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("fill",function(d){return color()})
      .attr("d", d3.area()
        .x(function(d,i){ console.log("Data on line", d.data); return x(d3.timeParse("%Y")(d.data.key)) })
        .y0(function(d) {console.log(d[0] +"-> y0: "+y(d[0])); return y(d[0])})
        .y1(function(d){ console.log(d[1] + "-> y1: "+y(d[1])); return y(d[1])})
        )
}else{
  d3.select("#chart").append("Error loading data")
}
```

Here's the structure of `data`:

[image]

```
(33) […]
​
0: {…}
​​
"Electricity by CSP": 0
​​
"Electricity by PV": 0
​​
"Electricity by geothermal": 0
​​
"Electricity by hydropower": 300.89983280022
​​
"Electricity by marine power": 0
​​
"Electricity by offshore wind": 0
​​
"Electricity by onshore wind": 0
​​
"Renewable energy": 258.219863514757
​​
"Solid bioenergy": 254.640155086192
​​
"Total demand for coal": 3711.42425220673
​​
"Total demand for crude oil": 7523.960117178
​​
"Total demand for natural gas": 254.640155086192
​​
"Total demand for nuclear fuel": 2449.95477156234
​​
year: Date Mon Jan 01 1990 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
1: Object { "Total demand for natural gas": 3220.14298481777, "Total demand for crude oil": 277.599399485849, "Total demand for coal": 3662.11547993736, … }
​
2: Object { "Total demand for natural gas": 3200.81379949803, "Total demand for crude oil": 7756.9933670896, "Total demand for coal": 273.508068071529, … }

...
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: 2020-02-21
I've posted a live version here: https://jsfiddle.net/turium/ywrbkzm9/

Comment: can you please create a working instance of your issue with data ?

Comment: @JasdeepSingh thanks for your message, I've edited the answer so it now includes a link to a should-be-working instance on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and there were couple of errors. I have replaced them with correct one, you can do your R&D on top of it.

- color function was not getting called from where you were appending path.
- there was unnecessary nesting of data.
- created a empty model object so jsfiddle was giving an error
- removed the time scale as it was adding overhead

Code to show x axis with years without commas.

```
svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(function(d) {
  return d;
}));
```

```js
model = {}
model.year = [
  1990,
  1991,
  1992,
  1993,
  1994,
  1995,
  1996,
  1997,
  1998,
  1999,
  2000,
  2001,
  2002,
  2003,
  2004,
  2005,
  2006,
  2007,
  2008,
  2009,
  2010,
  2011,
  2012,
  2013,
  2014,
  2015,
  2020,
  2025,
  2030,
  2035,
  2040,
  2045,
  2050
]
model.output_energy_demand = [
  [
"Total demand for natural gas",
"Total demand for crude oil",
"Total demand for coal",
"Electricity by geothermal",
"Electricity by hydropower",
"Electricity by marine power",
"Electricity by CSP",
"Electricity by PV",
"Electricity by offshore wind",
"Electricity by onshore wind",
"Total demand for nuclear fuel",
"Renewable energy",
"Solid bioenergy"
  ],
  [
3102.40524991691,
7523.960117178,
3711.42425220673,
0,
300.89983280022,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
2449.95477156234,
258.219863514757,
254.640155086192
  ],
  [
3220.14298481777,
7805.34286934201,
3662.11547993736,
0,
314.08215981732,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
2392.85347025885,
281.174663414415,
277.599399485849
  ],
  [
3200.81379949803,
7756.9933670896,
3445.10585509343,
0,
340.4890868346,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
2512.86260946551,
277.266526000094,
273.508068071529
  ],
  [
3305.31292778359,
7783.82326263428,
3472.68950574908,
0,
353.62925132022,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
2666.91820506714,
305.773519651316,
302.045477722751
  ],
  [
3367.00236478057,
7565.09225038114,
3413.93067723008,
0,
367.522212360599,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
2657.48508853596,
292.303360572476,
288.50963564391
  ],
  [
3487.48732706185,
7615.43451245472,
3406.94135763491,
0,
362.74326344874,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
2720.41544041992,
297.511985344959,
293.709384916393
  ],
  [
3744.9593399799,
7826.17851688842,
3449.136453147,
0,
355.3673026203,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
2871.17913811302,
323.48891655571,
319.711924627145
  ],
  [
3734.32219482531,
7545.58234604822,
3285.22078771847,
0,
367.27291222956,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
2895.07611993084,
333.778821035599,
329.987640607034
  ],
  [
3834.40132308377,
7645.80240057448,
3258.37777947803,
0,
377.0867016027,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
2889.95225758379,
334.216219338001,
330.408223409436
  ],
  [
3934.10235529276,
7393.72102051037,
3147.43143379234,
0,
383.18690200752,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
2914.35741090846,
327.381123667362,
323.534358238797
  ],
  [
4087.04502061623,
7247.4110570115,
3353.99479917852,
4.82547708666,
393.52232123964,
0.5071937472,
0,
0.203524605,
0,
26.81745703056,
2931.59347644636,
332.014849186351,
326.489968757786
  ],
  [
4187.85080191466,
7646.26147968543,
3384.51199334096,
4.64857517429999,
420.262811562959,
0.4852086192,
0,
0.30943918638,
0,
33.45917086152,
3022.71240680316,
336.487547234091,
330.881864107789
  ],
  [
4205.18925700953,
7579.67080593577,
3385.97805263338,
4.79569679315999,
353.99917660788,
0.494507592,
0,
0.4051566306,
0,
46.3006537083,
3067.10289195713,
337.738844971462,
332.131957416555
  ],
  [
4428.70123473367,
7834.71813308874,
3524.45624865725,
5.4612635832,
343.52520531084,
0.4898581056,
0,
0.72565105788,
0,
50.9478361405199,
3069.27182555567,
374.37075694017,
368.147127662413
  ],
  [
4551.82743034029,
8009.62808231553,
3449.96219341097,
5.564770758,
362.514048853499,
0.470082009599999,
0,
1.46273236614,
0,
67.69761449058,
3119.33911585662,
366.098265091526,
359.153478032005
  ],
  [
4604.74358239693,
8096.18416223813,
3381.05306785008,
5.44094040114,
344.3848462566,
0.4813375536,
0,
2.64236395716,
0,
78.3154704733199,
3066.35144843448,
386.969328558568,
379.391483494566
  ],
  [
4560.10999341729,
8203.04705336058,
3469.86003803626,
5.61711543678,
346.81026188232,
0.4642543728,
0,
3.73148887734,
0,
91.38316529736,
3050.45111617217,
394.148276719482,
385.458486662152
  ],
  [
4519.7188056018,
7948.7483718475,
3463.98671155763,
5.82834632004,
349.48220898564,
0.4654325232,
0.00484251372,
6.14455873164,
0,
118.81064914452,
2896.72897237308,
411.77345085889,
401.790597859782
  ],
  [
4642.45980752563,
8095.41788904162,
3208.68777524172,
5.78038393997999,
368.10858903516,
0.4654325232,
0.0094111776,
12.7615925908799,
2.60895690648,
132.13721227626,
2918.12383597752,
446.017117805582,
433.655553095456
  ],
  [
4300.19124830045,
7719.81278137145,
2876.38739207936,
5.58780088086,
371.310269112539,
0.44894025846,
0.11373727212,
20.3917959088199,
5.744841114762,
145.29539623914,
2921.42403037908,
467.905545984921,
453.394070650256
  ],
  [
4692.03986900568,
7797.53751476991,
2959.25747160129,
5.6382101145,
412.797954991499,
0.477972636839999,
0.8062598628,
35.0866669474799,
8.22484405134,
157.81866688674,
2856.24810989478,
498.364549610955,
481.466736916603
  ],
  [
4235.58374324098,
7538.66495957225,
3005.00134812211,
5.91160946975999,
344.426769476279,
0.478098341279999,
1.3839112116,
66.1100621738399,
11.72086686054,
179.46124283664,
2799.25195982939,
442.390139292031,
425.641578089282
  ],
  [
4107.70809841702,
7399.30695265121,
3137.64857648784,
5.80847765508,
374.23402394886,
0.46268411922,
3.98578825818,
86.04398912724,
16.05857548068,
204.94524478734,
2736.84193438788,
495.32616138678,
475.76987559724
  ],
  [
4043.0896536257,
7415.72476474021,
3039.06605229034,
5.97630596849999,
409.64636857176,
0.420999422399999,
5.21086402044,
94.70094727536,
21.5588025313199,
227.79819933624,
2708.12027152385,
505.670520272608,
483.316979888301
  ],
  [
3598.13284429141,
7317.86276802473,
2846.1651910181,
6.26113715202,
412.580152851659,
0.48353974812,
5.89504961916,
102.0072482082,
25.42716943056,
240.05775513006,
2711.96611313418,
454.88706631646,
432.892324258519
  ],
  [
3754.93540354624,
7511.65923877049,
2800.70818111911,
6.6793685346,
380.261269231019,
0.495524623319999,
6.07585064832,
114.06062251008,
39.85985729862,
276.41099985318,
2645.38509787332,
495.328376085096,
465.28909250104
  ],
  [
4043.59078735007,
8017.18489716505,
2338.95806864845,
6.7875256341,
394.603505735554,
0.51747170688,
6.07585064832,
145.892562054913,
83.1198330814429,
408.732059173849,
2480.44614477944,
427.441506546882,
409.905742992792
  ],
  [
3291.51973731274,
4997.05071692697,
452.188235416201,
63.9709506160571,
446.050495741098,
11.6326046301965,
85.869709014152,
220.181406509467,
609.256812048776,
529.707140310043,
2717.66461431481,
593.564950874224,
388.443809434111
  ],
  [
2885.96717926539,
2676.62515437839,
293.191002866746,
121.154375598014,
498.701133634033,
22.747737553513,
165.663567379984,
293.862964912845,
1131.43400447885,
649.689673274539,
2893.87542604889,
676.605125561303,
339.139457453926
  ],
  [
2664.88017244303,
1096.4584151475,
233.59485578412,
178.337800579971,
543.439537600747,
33.8628704768296,
245.457425745816,
367.884313156941,
1650.85948123489,
769.503145366082,
2732.03449314671,
636.789912347858,
258.105935984877
  ],
  [
2546.12143825256,
383.69776070687,
144.591148980276,
235.521225561928,
587.785639945705,
44.9780034001461,
325.251284111648,
441.672179518208,
2167.12983644434,
889.008654837177,
2379.90569231828,
511.758583755248,
174.052538556381
  ],
  [
2597.56379334278,
275.045700399492,
98.1839204037293,
292.704650543886,
631.738388993547,
56.0931363234626,
405.04514247748,
515.225029663832,
2680.25396805022,
1007.80883971052,
1913.52680335554,
530.552643420933,
153.689961713093
  ],
  [
2749.62249643278,
192.082054109743,
61.7232837841147,
349.888075525843,
681.054211190302,
67.2082692467792,
484.839000843312,
587.790589413631,
3189.00909148252,
1125.32442426428,
1779.67241790878,
550.847796398766,
135.833335875956
  ]
]

//Draw graph
var margin = {
top: 10,
right: 30,
bottom: 30,
left: 70
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let data = []
var group_names = []
//Assumes first line of data is table header, otherwise will not work properly
debugger;
model.output_energy_demand.map(function(x, i) {
  if (i == 0) {
group_names = x
  } else {
let line = {}
x.map(function(y, j) {
  line[group_names[j]] = y
});
data.push(line)
  }
});

/* data.forEach((d, i) => {
  var keys = Object.keys(d)
  d.year = model.year[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
d[keys[i]] = +d[keys[j]]
  }
}); */

data.forEach((d, i) => {
d['year'] = model.year[i];
});


if (typeof(data) != "undefined") {

  var stackedData = d3.stack()
.keys(group_names)
(data);
debugger;
  //Set up axes
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain(d3.extent(model.year.map((d, i) => {
  return d
})))
.range([0, width])


  svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(function(d) {
  return d;
}));
  svg.append("text")
.attr("x", width * 0.5)
.attr("y", height + margin.bottom)
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("font-family", "Tahoma")
.text("Year")

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([0, d3.max(stackedData,
  function(d) {
    //Find maximum value of data
    var max = 0;
    d.forEach(function(e, i) {
      if (d3.max(e) > max) max = d3.max(e)
    })
    return max
  })])
.range([height, 0])

  svg.append("g")
.call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  svg.append("text")
.attr("y", -margin.left)
.attr("x", -height * 0.5)
.attr("dy", "1em")
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("font-family", "Tahoma")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.text("Energy Demand (TWh /year)")


  svg
.selectAll("layers")
.data(stackedData)
.enter()
.append("path")
.style("fill", function(d) {
  var n = Math.random() * (16 ** 7 - 1)
  let val = (n.toString(16)).slice(0, 6)
  return `#${val}`;
})

.attr("d", d3.area()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return x(d.data.year)
  })
  .y0(function(d) {
    return y(d[0])
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    return y(d[1])
  })
)
} else {
  d3.select("#chart").append("Error loading data")
}
```

```css
body {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
}

#header {
  height: 56px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #666666;
}

#header div {
  padding: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

#header span {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-shadow: #000000 1px
}

#content {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <!--<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>-->
  <title>Stacked Area Chart</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div>
      <span>Stacked Area Chart</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h2>Demo 1: Basic Graph</h2>
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </div>
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/stacked_graph1.js"></script>-->
</body>

</html>
```

The below code was messing the data, so replaced it with much easier code to add years to dataset.

```
// Commented below code as it was distorting current dataset
/* data.forEach((d, i) => {
  var keys = Object.keys(d)
  d.year = model.year[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
d[keys[i]] = +d[keys[j]
  }
}); */

// Use below code.
data.forEach((d, i) => {
    d['year'] = model.year[i];
});
```

Tested the data with excel and getting the same output[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @Jasdeep, I'd been stuck on it for a week. Of course an unnecessary ``nest()`` function! Also, well spotted with the overhead from the date function, though it does put a comma in now (e.g. 1,996 instead of 1996). Is there a better way to do dates you can suggest?

Comment: This goes a little beyond the original question, but I've just noticed that the stacked area chart produced by this code is not correct when compared with the output of another graphing software. There shouldn't be a dip around the point labelled "2000". Can't think what I am doing wrong, as the data type should be set correctly as a number.

Comment: Wondering if the above issue (see other comment) may be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415665/dc-js-stacked-area-chart-using-reducecount-method

Comment: I have updated the code to fix x axis labels. Now the years will appear without commas. I need to look into issue regarding the issue of dip near point label 2000. I need to look into data as well.

Comment: I have checked and i can see there are some zeros value in data. This can cause next year value to be less than current year. Why do you think that there should not be dip. Please help me to understand. Even the chart shared by you has dips - https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/stackedarea_wideinput.html

Comment: Thanks for updating the code to fix the x-axis labels

Comment: Almost! About the dips, I have used different data to the one in the example. The link is to give context to the plotting method, not for the data. When I have ploted the data in Excel or a different graphing software, there is no dip around 2000. The code also makes the plot start from zero in 1990, though the values passed for 1990 are non-zero. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Arty, Fixed the issue of unnecessary dips. I have also mentioned the source of error. Please let me know if it resolve your issue.

Comment: Excellent, that has solved the issue. Nice work @Jasdeep

Comment: Glad to help you!